# Using a USP Window Bug in a Custom Circuit

Tags: arduino, power, sensor

I have a United Security Window Bug glass break detector. I would like to interface it in someway to a program I am writing on a laptop computer. The sensor is a dry circuit and has a broken pulse time of 10 milliseconds. I am not that great with electronics but am experienced with arduinos and am willing to bit hack a USB port.

The sensor only has a single red and black wire, should I provide power through these wires, if so how much? How do I detect a break event?

Thank you for any advice or help.

Comment: Datasheet where?

Comment: Datasheet was my first goto, but all I could find was this sec sheet http://download.homesecuritystore.com/downloadmanual.aspx?FileName=724_Spec.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> - Dry Circuit
> - No Power Required
> - Adjustable Operation of OC or CC

Sounds like a switch to me. Connect one end to ground and the other end to an interrupt pin with pullup enabled, enable the interrupt to detect the appropriate transition, and run with it.